# Dummy Coding of Nominal Attributes - Effect of Using K Dummies, Effect of Attribute Selection

Tags: attributes, statistics, data-mining, weka, regression

Summing up my understanding of the topic **'Dummy Coding'** is usually understood as coding a nominal attribute with K possible values as K-1 binary dummies. The usage of K values would cause redundancy and would have a negative impact e.g. on logistic regression, as far as I learned it. That far, everything's clear to me.

***Yet, two issues are unclear to me:***

1) Bearing in mind the issue stated above, I am confused that the *'Logistic'* classifier in WEKA actually uses K dummies (see picture). *Why would that be the case?*

2) An issue arises as soon as I consider attribute selection. Where the left-out attribute value is implicitly included as the case where all dummies are zero if all dummies are actually used for the model, it isn't included clearly anymore, if one dummy is missing (as not selected in attribute selection). The issue is much easy to understand with the sketch I uploaded. *How can that issue be treated?*

Secondly

***Images***

**WEKA Output:** The Logistic algorithm was run on the UCI dataset German Credit, where the possible values of the first attribute are A11,A12,A13,A14. All of them are included in the logistic regression model. http://abload.de/img/bildschirmfoto2013-089out9.png

**Decision Tree Example:** Sketch showing the issue when it comes to running decision trees on datasets with dummy-coded instances after attribute selection. http://abload.de/img/sketchziu5s.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is generally more **easy to read, interpret and use** when you use k dummies instead of k-1 dummies. I figure that is why everybody seems to actually use k dummies.
But yes, as the k values sum up to 1, there exists a correlation that may cause problems. But correlations in data sets are common, you will never completely get rid of them!

I believe feature selection and dummy coding just doesn't fit. It equals **dropping some values** from the attribute. Why do you insist on doing feature selection?

You really should be using weighting, or consider more advanced algorithms that can handle such data. In fact the **dummy variables can cause just as much trouble**, because they are binary, and oh so many algorithms (e.g. k-means) don't make much sense on binary variables.

As for the decision tree: **don't perform, feature selection on your *output* attribute**...
Plus, as a decision tree already selects features, it does not make sense to do all this anyway... leave it to the decision tree to decide upon which attribute to use for splitting. This way, it can learn dependencies, too.